# Ошибка room java в release версии

Tags: java, android

Использую room java Android. При отладке в IDE все работает нормально, apk-собирается нормально, работает. При публикации app.bundle в Google Play выдает ошибку:

```
2022-07-25 15:26:20.642 10050-3963/? W/NetworkScheduler: Error inserting period=2000 preferred_charging_state=1 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService required_network_type=0 runtime=1658751980639 required_idleness_state=0 source=16 service_kind=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms persistence_level=1 source_version=222615000 last_runtime=0 user_id=0 job_id=-1 requires_charging=0 tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG flex_time=0 task_type=0 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:796)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1459)
        at bgif.g(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):52)
        at bggy.n(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):3)
        at bggy.u(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):20)
        at bggy.h(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):3)
        at bgcp.run(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):9)
        at zeu.c(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):6)
        at zeu.run(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at zjz.run(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Ошибка появляется ТОЛЬКО в релизной версии после публикации.

Comment: Вот тут возможно что-то найдете: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/361

Answer (score 1):

Установил:
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false

Ошибка пропала. Но это не выход, а временная мера. Как быть?